# All the text from cardview is not showing in scrollview

Tags: android, text, scrollview, android-cardview

i am trying to make `CardView` with text inside it but the problem is i am not able to scroll through entire text section, some part of text is missing at the end.
How to solve this?

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"

android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="start"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_view_princitext"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pmsg"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i don't know why you set height of scrollview to 0dp so why some views in side it can be show. Let set height to match_parent or a other valid number

Answer (score 4):

Change this line

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Root layout cannot have `layout_weight` property, it will not make any effect

Comment: i think the problem is something else i did what you said but the last two or so lines are not showing

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem with your support library which you are using for cardview. The compiled sdk version and support lib version should be same.

for example:
In build.gradle

if compileSdkVersion 23  then

in dependencies you should use

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'

Check both the versions in build.gradle.

ps: if you use support lib version 24 studio suggest you the following

"this support library should not use a different version (24) than the compilesdkversion (23)"

best luck !